# Highlighting the Selected Row GridView

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

when the user click on Edit from the gridview i want to highlight the row and here is what i have done but no effect. what else i am missing?

```
.SelectedRowStyle
{
    background-color: Yellow;
}

<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="DataWebControlStyle">
   <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" />
   <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
   <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
   <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how i able to fix:

```
if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow & ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit))) {   
         e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow;   
     }
```

Comment: Rick, i am sorry for late response but i dont remember exactly where i have added.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `EditRowStyle`?

```
.EditRowStyle
{
    background-color: Yellow;
}

<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="DataWebControlStyle">
   <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" />
   <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
   <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
   <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: i just tried with editrowstyle but does not highlight the row, may be because of postback?

Comment: Probably because the `CssClass` doesn't relate to the CSS class

Answer (score 1):

The EditRowStyle class is applied to the `<tr>` not the `<td>`. So if you did `.SelectedRowStyle td` the css would be applied correctly.

This is what I use:

```
<EditRowStyle CssClass="selectedRowStyle" />
```

Then CSS

```
.selectedRowStyle td
{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

May be this line of code help you:

```
.DataWebControlStyle tr:hover
{
    background-color: Yellow;
}

<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="DataWebControlStyle">
   <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" />
   <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
   <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
</asp:GridView>
```